# Laravel 5.5: Authorization with pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have four table `users`, `groups`, `posts`, and `group_user`. Users can follow different groups. The `group_user table` is for many-to-many relationship.

Every post belongs to a group and a user. I want that a user can only post a post on a group if he follows that group. I can easily check using `if` statement that whether a user follows that group or not. But how can I authorize the user for posting using policies.

Comment: Its really too broad , share specific question with code.

Comment: ok, trying to find out some information about this. Will update this question wherever I'll stick.

Answer (score 1):

Create a policy:`php artisan make:policy`.

Register policy:

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        Post::class => PostPolicy::class,
    ];
```

In your policy the logic, for instance:

```
public function create(User $user, Post $post)
{
    $groupsOfUser = $user->groups()->get();

    foreach ($groupsOfUser as $group) {
        if($group->id == request('groupId'))return true;
    }
}
```

And in your Controller:

```
public function store(Post $post, $groupId)
{
    $this->authorize('create', $post);

    Post::create([
        'user_id' =>auth()->id(),
        'group_id' => $groupId,
        'title' => 'sometitle',
    ]);
}
```

And i have tested it with route:

```
Route::get('/post/{groupId}', 'PostController@store');
```

But you may be getting groupId via input, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any good answers for this so I'll share what I did to help out anyone looking for this in the future.

This was tested in laravel 5.8 but I think it will work at least a few versions back.

First create a pivot model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class GroupUser extends Pivot {}
```

Update your `groups` relationship in the `User` model

```
public function groups() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class)
        ->using(GroupUser::class);
}
```

And update your `users` relationship in the `Group` model

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
        ->using(GroupUser::class);
}
```

Create your `GroupUserPolicy` class

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class GroupUserPolicy {
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function update(User $user, GroupUser $pivot) {
        // check permissions
    }

    // additional authorization methods
}
```

And link them up in the `AuthServiceProvider` if not using auto discover

```
protected $policies = [
    GroupUser::class => GroupUserPolicy::class,
    // ...
];
```

Then when you want to show or update a pivot, in a controller for example, then you can just pass the pivot to the authorize check

```
$group = $user->groups()->where('group_id', $groupId)->firstOrFail();
$this->authorize('update', $group->pivot);

// or ...

foreach ($user->groups as $group) {
    $this->authorize('update', $group->pivot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a complex solution for Access Control List. Read about Zizaco Entrust Library. Here you can set permissions for each route in your system. By that routing and permission you can prepare few groups. 
Topic is hard but realy worth to implement:
https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust